# Does a primitive array length reflect the allocated size or the number of assigned elements?

Tags: java, arrays

I declared an array as shown below:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

Then I assigned following values to the array:

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
```

Then I declared and initialized an integer variable:

```
int arrayLength = arr.length;
```

Will `arrayLength` contain 10, the allocated size of the array or 4, the count of elements that have been explicitly assigned?

Comment: This question has 1 million views due to the extremely generic title that hasn't reflected the content of the question well until 2022, but I don't understand why OP didn't simply [run the code](https://web.archive.org/web/20170723230450/http://importblogkit.com/2017/02/will-this-work/) to see what the output was, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It contains the allocated size, `10`. The unassigned indexes will contain the default value which is `0` for `int`.

Comment: Yes, arrays are static memory allocation.

Comment: Can you show the javadoc? I don't know where this "length" property is.

Comment: @PhilipRego It's in the language specification https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3

Answer (score 75):

First of all, `length` is a property, so it would be `arr.length` instead of `arr.length()`.

And it will return 10, the declared size. The elements that you do not declare explicitely are initialized with 0.

Comment: Cannot invoke length() on the array type long[]Java(67108980)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano yep, that's exactly what the answer said would happen.

Answer (score 22):

To find length of an array `A` you should use the `length` property. It is as `A.length`, do not use `A.length()` its mainly used for size of string related objects.

[image]

The length property will always show the total allocated space to the array during initialization.

If you ever have any of these kind of problems the simple way is to run it. Happy Programming!

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are static memory allocation, so if you initialize an array of integers:

```
int[] intArray = new int[15];
```

The length will be **always** 15, no matter how many indexes are filled.

And another thing, when you intialize an array of integers, *all the indexes will be filled with "0".*

Answer (score 6):

In this case, arr.length will return 10, the size of array you allocated. Logical size doesn't really apply here, as this is a fixed length array.

When you initialize the array:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

Java will create an array with 10 elements and initialize all of these to 0. See the [Java language spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5) for details of initial values for this and other primitive types.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, your "actual" and "logical" size are the same. The run-time fills all array slots with default values upon allocation. So, your `a` contains 10.

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

`arr` is an `int` type array which has size `10`. It is an array of `10` elements.
If we don't initialize an array by default array elements contains default value. In case of int array default value is `0`.

length is a property which is applicable for an array.
here `arr.length` will give `10`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int array[] = new int[3];
array.length;
```

Here we have created an array with a memory space of 3.
This is how it looks actually:

```
0th  1st 2nd ...........>  Index
2     4   5  ...........> Number
```

As you can see, the size of this array is 3 but the index of array is only up to 2 since any array starts with 0th index.

The second statement's output shall be 3 since the length of the array is 3. Please don't get confused between the index value and the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

It will contain the actual size of the array as that is what you initialized the array to be when you declared it. Java has no concept of the "logical" size of an array, as far as it is concerned the default value of 0 is just as logical as the values you have manually set.

Answer (score 2):

```
  int arr[]={4,7,2,21321,657,12321};
  int length =arr.length;
  System.out.println(length); // will return 6

  int arr2[] = new int[10];
   arr2[3] = 4;
  int length2 =arr2.length;
  System.out.println(length2); // // will return 10. all other digits will be 0 initialize because staic memory initialization
```

Answer (score 1):

It contains the allocated size, 10. The remaining indexes will contain the default value which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the logical size of the array, you can traverse all the values in the array and check them against zero. Increment the value if it is not zero and that would be the logical size. Because array size is fixed, you do not have any inbuilt method, may be you should have a look at collections.

Comment: This is just an "I assume 0 is not a valid value" size and if that is helpful is kind of doubtful.

Comment: I just came up with an idea to obtain the length of the array (0's are invalid). As i said you can use collections for more precise data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
int a = arr.length;
```

Parenthesis should be avoided.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Since this a question that's well over a year old, and already has six other answers, I would expect a longe answer than this. Moreover, you're not answering the point of the question - merely fixing a typo that has already been targeted in an answer (which answers the question) _and_ a question comment.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are actually fixed in size, and the other answers explain how .length isn't really doing what you'd expect. I'd just like to add that given your question what you might want to be using is an ArrayList, that is an array that can grow and shrink:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Here the .size() method will show you the number of elements in your list, and you can grow this as you add things.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are allocated memory at compile time in java, so they are static, the elements not explicitly set or modified are set with the default values. You could use some code like this, though it is not recommended as it does not count default values, even if you explicitly initialize them that way, it is also likely to cause bugs down the line. As others said, when looking for the actual size, ".length" must be used instead of ".length()".

```
public int logicalArrayLength(type[] passedArray) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < passedArray.length; i++) {
        if (passedArray[i] != defaultValue) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you mean by "logical size", the index of array, then simply
    int arrayLength = arr.length-1;
since the the array index starts with "0", so the logical or "array index" will always be less than the actual size by "one".

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking about. OP wants to know whether the `.length` property  refers to the total length or the number of initialized elements, not the last element index as in this interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add,

In **Java** all the arrays are indexed and declared by **int only**. That is the size of an array `must be specified by an int value and not long or short`. All the arrays index beginning from 0 to ends at **2147483646**. You can store elements up to **2147483647**. If you try to store long (big) elements in the array, you will get performance problems. If you overcome performance problems you should go to the java collections framework.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?