# How does this for-loop know how long this array datastructure will be from the start?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, data-structures, final

I am trying to figure out how the array knows that there are a total of 15 indexes from the first run of System.out.println in the for-loop, and from where EXACTLY it knows it.

It seems to know the total number of indexes while the for-loop is still executing, and I thought that once an array is created, that it cannot be changed. Is the array in a temporary state while it's being constructed, or is the answer much simpler than I'm making it?

I'm making guesses at the possible answer, and I do not know for sure. Please help! Thank you in advance.

My sole purpose in using this code is to evaluate the resulting output at the bottom compared to the code used to create it, and determine how this particular for-loop constructs the array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DataStructureMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class DataStructure {

            //Create an array
            private final static int SIZE = 15;
            private int[] anArrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

            public DataStructure() {

                //Fill the array with ascending integer values
                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                    anArrayOfInts[i] = i;
                    //I put this next line in here to see how the code 
                    //executes each run of the for-loop
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(anArrayOfInts));
                }
            }
        }

        //
        //
        DataStructure dS = new DataStructure();

    }

}
```

Produces this:

> `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0]
>       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`

Comment: You set `SIZE = 15;` then you use the same variable to construct the array by `private int[] anArrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];`. Once it is created its size is fixed. Then you use the same variable to limit the number of iterations by `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I didn't see that! So you're saying that the length of the array is set from the time the object is created with `private int[] anArrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];` and it is THEN populated by the for-loop, am I correct in understanding you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set

 `SIZE = 15;` 

then you use the same variable to construct the array by

 `private int[] anArrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];`. 

Once it is created its size is fixed. 

Then you use the same variable to limit the number of iterations by 

`for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)` 


Alternatively you could use : 

`for (int i = 0; i <  anArrayOfInts.length ; i++)` 

 which would give you the same result.

Comment: Yup. In other words, Java knows because you told it so! Arrays in Java know their own length, too; hence, when you pass the array to `Arrays#toString(Object[])`, that method is easily able to know the length as well. The `Arrays` method doesn't have access to your `SIZE` variable; it's getting that from the array itself.

Answer (score -2):

you are using:

```
private final static int SIZE = 15;
```

and then using this SIZE variable through out the program. so compiler does not do anything to check the size of the array,as you are specifying the size everytime.

Instead you can use this code to understand more:

```
Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);  // to take input from user;
int n;
n = s.nextInt();    // takes integer input from user.
int arr[]=new int[n];    //array of size n,specified by user

for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)       //in place of arr.length you can use n also
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

arr.length is a property so it will not be arr.length() (which is a function), and it contains the length of the array.

For more information, you can visit this link:
[Array Length in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755812/array-length-in-java)

Comment: Overcomplicated; ser JohnG can probably wait until after he's mastered Arrays before worrying about I/O libraries.