# Can someone help me visually understand how array.length - 1 is at the end of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve a binary sort problem in Java. I can't wrap my head around why the end of the array would be array.length - 1.

if

```
int[] array = [0,1,2,3,4]

int start = 0;
int end = array.length - 1;
```

Wouldn't end return 3?

Comment: No, the length of this array is 5. Minus 1 gives 4.

Comment: Indices start counting at 0. So your array with 5 elements has indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: What do you think `array.length` returns and why do you obviously think it's `4`?

Comment: Indices aren't relevant, really. There are 5 things in the array, its length is 5. -1 is 4.

Comment: If you need a visualization, there is a picture in the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: I really would like to know why these kinds of questions attract heaps of identical answers. I understand that it's simple to answer, but it's a duplicate, and if the exact same answer has already been posted 3 times, why bother?

Comment: @Moira you often don't see the other answers until you've finished writing your own, what with being "heads-down quick-typing this easy answer".

Comment: @AndyTurner I understand, though I would usually rather delete my own and upvote the best existing answer, especially when it's a one-liner :P

Comment: @Moira Often I find my answers tailored to what I need by asking for what I want, I'm sorry if it sounds really simple to google but how am I going to learn if I dont learn how to ask questions and not google?

Comment: @Moira "but I've written it now, so I may as well leave it." <shrug> Who knows.

Comment: @evanparial I was primarily referring to the answers to this question rather than to the question itself; apologies if it came across wrong. I didn't downvote and I think -6 is fairly harsh for a misunderstanding, especially when the question probably should've just been closed as a duplicate and otherwise left alone, but...

Comment: [One of the dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755812/array-length-in-java) doesn't seem to correspond well to this question.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

The term **index** (something like position) starts counting at `0`.

So your array, which has 5 elements, has elements at indices `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. So the last element is indeed at index `4`, which is `length - 1`.

So visualized, for an array like `{ 3, 6, 1, 8, 4 }` we have

```
values:  3 6 1 8 4
indices: 0 1 2 3 4
```

---

### Background

I suppose one of the strongest reasons why the indices (at least in Java and many other languages) start counting at `0` has to do with how it is implemented under the hood, as in:

```
array[i]
```

basically being computed as

```
sizeof(type) * i
```

to get hands on the actual memory address offset. And having `0` there would result in an offset of `0`, so the beginning of the memory for this array.

There are actually languages that did not go this route, like Matlab where *indices* start counting at `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Array length would be 5, since there are 5 elements in the array.

Element `0` is the 1st element (index 0), element `1` is the second (index 1), ..., element `4` is the fifth (index 4).

So the index of the last element is `5-1 = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

This list is of length 5. The last index is 4, though, because the first index is 0 (not 1).

Answer (score 1):

`array.length` is 5.

In Java, you start counting arrays at 0, so `array[0]` would be 0.

Count upwards, and you'll find that the last element of that array, (as you have defined it) has index position 4, ie `array.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start at 0.

Sizes/Lengths start at 1.

Array length = 5;

Last elemnt is in Index the length - 1 (the difference between sizes/lengths indexes.